# How to get progress of file upload using requests.post() if the file was just uploaded via form-data? (Not sure whether this is a streaming process)

Tags: python, ajax, flask, python-requests

Suppose I'm running some kind of web service with python & flask aiming to provide file upload. It should be noted that my service is only a kind of transfer station, which means I'll "repost" the file elsewhere, say, a massive centralized file storage, as soon as I receive a file from frontend form-data. The flask code looks like this:

```py
@admin.route('/data', methods=['POST'])
def data_upload():
    if 'file' in request.files:
        f = request.files['file']
        try:
            r = Requests.post(DataConfig.server + '/' + '/upload.php', files={'file': (f.filename, f)})
            return {'e': 0, 'msg': r.content.decode('utf-8')}
        except RequestException:
            return ReturnCode.ERR_NETWORK_FAILURE
    return ReturnCode.ERR_BAD_DATA
```

It is not allowed that the frontend directly send file or data to "upload.php", since the server key should not be exposed to users.

Now I've got two problems that confuse me.

- Is this process streaming or streaming-ready? I mean, whether my python server will receive the file and store it somewhere temporarily, or the file will be repost in chunks, like **iter_block**? If streaming is not readily enabled, how can I do so to enable large-file uploading user experience?
- Is it possible to provide the user (frontend, browser) information about the progress of uploading?

For question 2, there exists some posts indicating that tqdm will help, but tqdm is a cli tool and printing anything in the python server's terminal makes no sense, and document of tqdm doesn't show me any obvious reference about their apis to get a percentage. What's more, I think that maybe sending this percentage to frontend may require some xhr techniques, which I believe my code can't deal with.

Comment: Try https://pythonise.com/articles/upload-progress-bar-xmlhttprequest.

Comment: I'll answer soon, in the mean time you can see https://www.stubfees.com/templates/tests_ubox_slice/slice.html just check the source code... I'm also doing upload chunks.... and I use https://filebase.com/ for storage (WAY MORE affordable that AWS, and others....)

Comment: I answered (PART 1) the javascript part, I'm finalizing the php receiver part.

Comment: I completed my answer and also made a github https://github.com/jintor/ajax_upload_chunks_recombine_php

Answer (score 0):

PART 1 OF MY ANSWER : THE JAVASCRIPT

```
async function ubox_send_chucks (divid) {
    
    var chunstart = 0;
    var chunend = 0;
    var chunksize = 1024 * 1024 * 9;
    var newblobchun_id = parseInt(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000000) + 1);
    fi = $("#"+divid).files;
    stubuploads = fi.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < fi.length; i++) { 
        var thismediaby_id = (newblobchun_id + i + 3); 
        $("#progressx").append("<div id=\'loaderz_"+thismediaby_id+"_message\' class=\'padding3 margin3\' >FILE "+i+" (PREP)</div>"); 
        $("#phpx").append("<div id=\'phpz_"+thismediaby_id+"_message\' class=\'padding3 margin3\' >FILE "+i+" (PREP)</div>"); 
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < fi.length; i++) {
    
        if ( fi[i].size > 0 ) {
        
            var numberofchunks = Math.ceil( fi[i].size / chunksize );
            var thismediaby_id = (newblobchun_id + i + 3);
            
            logx("FILE "+i+" -- size: "+fi[i].size+" name: "+fi[i].name+" n of chunks to send: "+numberofchunks );
        
            // SEND EACH CHUNKS
            for (var c = 0; c <= numberofchunks; c++) {
            
                chunstart = (c * chunksize); chunend = chunstart + chunksize + 1; if ( chunend > fi[i].size ){ chunend = fi[i].size; }
                
                var thischunk = fi[i].slice(chunstart, chunend);
                var thismediaby_name = thismediaby_id+"--chunk_"+c;
                
                console.log("FILE "+i+" send chunk: "+c+" start: "+chunstart+" end: "+chunend);
            
                upload_percent = ( c / numberofchunks ) * 100;
                $("#loaderz_"+thismediaby_id+"_message").html("FILE "+i+" : " + Math.round(upload_percent) + " %");
        
                var fd = new FormData(); 
                fd.append("data", thischunk, encodeURIComponent(thismediaby_name)); 
                fd.append("thismedia_id", encodeURIComponent(thismediaby_id)); 
                fd.append("thismedia_name", encodeURIComponent(fi[i].name)); 
                fd.append("numberofchunks", encodeURIComponent(numberofchunks)); 
                fd.append("thischunk_number", encodeURIComponent(c)); 
                fd.append("thisfilex", encodeURIComponent(i)); 
                fd.append("thissession", encodeURIComponent(thissession)); 
                fd.append("howmanyfiles", encodeURIComponent(fi.length)); 
                
                var pcache = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000000) + 1); 
                await fetch("/templates/tests_ubox_slice/slice_receiver.php?pcache="+pcache, { method: "POST", body: fd })
                    .then(function (response) { return response.text(); })
                    .then(function (html) { $("#php_message").html(html); })
        
            }
            
            // WHEN ALL CHUNKS SENT TRIGGER A RECOMBINE (SAFER)
            // AJAX FUNCTION HERE https://stubs.s3.filebase.com/media/stubs/202111100393/recookies.js
            var combinex = [];
            combinex["thismedia_id"] = encodeURIComponent(thismediaby_id); 
            combinex["thissession"] = encodeURIComponent(thissession); 
            combinex["thismedia_name"] = encodeURIComponent(fi[i].name); 
            stubajax("combiner","/templates/tests_ubox_slice/slice_combiner.php?pcache="+pcache,combinex);
                
        }
    
    }

}
```

PART II PHP RECEIVER

```
function clean () { ....stuff to make user input more secure like rawurldecode, html_entity_decode, stripslashes, etc }

$pcache = clean( $_REQUEST['pcache'] ?? '' ) ;
$thismedia_id = clean( $_REQUEST['thismedia_id'] ?? '' ) ;
$thismedia_name = clean( $_REQUEST['thismedia_name'] ?? '' );
$thismedia_ext = pathinfo($exif_file)['extension'] ?? '';
$numberofchunks = clean( $_REQUEST['numberofchunks'] ?? '' ) ;
$thischunk_number = clean( $_REQUEST['thischunk_number'] ?? '' ) ;
$thisfilex = clean( $_REQUEST['thisfilex'] ?? '' ) ;
$howmanyfiles = clean( $_REQUEST['howmanyfiles'] ?? '' ) ;
$thissession = clean( $_REQUEST['thissession'] ?? '' ) ;

if ( $pcache != '' ) {
    
    // DEV
    // var_dump(['thismedia_id'=>$thismedia_id,'thismedia_name'=>$thismedia_name,'numberofchunks'=>$numberofchunks,'thischunk_number'=>$thischunk_number,'thisfilex'=>$thisfilex]);

    // WHERE TO SAVE CHUNKS
    $received_chunk_dir = '/temporary_path_here_you_receiver_chunks/'.$thissession.'/'.$thismedia_id.'/';
    $received_chunk_path = $received_chunk_dir.$thismedia_id.'_chunk_'.$thischunk_number;

    // IF DIRECTORY NOT THERE CREATE IT
    if ( !file_exists($received_chunk_dir) ) { shell_exec('mkdir -p "'.$received_chunk_dir.'"'); }

    // MOVE_UPLOADED_FILE
    foreach ($_FILES as $thisfilekey => $thisfilechun) { 
        if ( isset($thisfilechun['name']) && isset($thisfilechun['tmp_name']) ) { 
            if ( filesize($thisfilechun['tmp_name']) > 1 ) { move_uploaded_file($thisfilechun['tmp_name'],$received_chunk_path); }
        }
    }
    
    // ECHO PERCENT PROGRESSION FOR THAT FILE
    echo '<script>$("#phpz_'.$thismedia_id.'_message").html("FILE '.$thisfilex.' : received chunk number '.$thischunk_number.' of '.$numberofchunks.' chunks");</script>';

}
```

PART III PHP COMBINER

```
$pcache = clean( $_REQUEST['pcache'] ?? '' ) ;
$thismedia_id = clean( $_REQUEST['thismedia_id'] ?? '' ) ;
$thismedia_name = accentx(clean( $_REQUEST['thismedia_name'] ?? '' ),'unlock');
$thismedia_ext = exiftensionx(['exif_file'=>$thismedia_name]);
$numberofchunks = clean( $_REQUEST['numberofchunks'] ?? '' ) ;
$thischunk_number = clean( $_REQUEST['thischunk_number'] ?? '' ) ;
$thisfilex = clean( $_REQUEST['thisfilex'] ?? '' ) ;
$howmanyfiles = clean( $_REQUEST['howmanyfiles'] ?? '' ) ;
$thissession = clean( $_REQUEST['thissession'] ?? '' ) ;

if ( $thissession != '' ) {

    // PATH
    $received_chunk_dir = '/temporary_path_here_you_receiver_chunks/'.$thissession;
    $received_final_path = $received_chunk_dir.'/'.$thismedia_id.'/'.$thismedia_id.'.'.$thismedia_ext;

    // GET OF SORTED FILES -V because chunk_1, chunk_2, ...., chunk_9, chunk_10, chunk_11 ==> dont want chunk_1,chunk_10,chunk_2 but chunk_1,chunk_2,...,chunk_10
    $all_chunks_raw = shell_exec('ls '.$received_chunk_dir.'/'.$thismedia_id.'/* | sort -V');
            
    if ( $all_chunks_raw != '' ) {

        // GET LS OF ALL CHUNKS
        $all_chunks_explo = array_filter(explode(PHP_EOL,$all_chunks_raw));
        
        // IF ONLY 1 CHUNK JUST RENAME
        if ( count($all_chunks_explo) == 1 ) { rename($all_chunks_explo[0],$received_final_path); @unlink($all_chunks_explo[0]); }
        else {
            // RECOMBINE ALL CHUNKS WITH FOPEN FREAD chunksize = 1024 * 1024 * 9 = 9437184 from javascript HAS TO BE THE SAME VALUE
            foreach ( $all_chunks_explo as $chunkey => $chunx ){    
                $file = fopen($chunx, 'rb'); $buff = fread($file, 9437184); fclose($file);
                $final = fopen($received_final_path, 'ab'); $write = fwrite($final, $buff); fclose($final);
            }
            // DELETE CHUNKS AFTER COMBINE
            shell_exec('ls '.$received_chunk_dir.'/'.$thismedia_id.' -name "*_chunk_*" -delete');
        }

    }
    
    // HERE YOU CAN FFMPEG, IMAGEMAGICK, ETC TO CONVERT TO WEB COMPATIBLE FORMAT
    
    // HERE YOU CAN SEND FILES TO S3 BUCKET (services like filebase.com)

    // DELETE FILE AFTER SENDING TO S3 BUCKET IF YOU NEED TO CLEAR SPACE

    echo '<script>$("#phpz_'.$thismedia_id.'_message").append(" ---COMBINATION DONE---");</script>';

}
```

******** NOTE : because of async: it's important to WAIT for all chuncks BEFORE combining because of networks (internet) factors, chunks don't always arrive one after an other, some times, you get chunk 1, then 3 then 6 then 2. it's why a ajax call sends a signal to combiner to "tell" ok, all chuncks are sent

[image]

Comment: Subscribing for part 2 :p

Comment: @ManishDash Hi, hope you enjoy, I re-edited the answer with ALL : re-modified javascript + php receiver + php combiner

Comment: @ManishDash I made a github out of it https://github.com/jintor/ajax_upload_chunks_recombine_php/tree/main